# How to get citations to render without placing bibliography in ConTeXt?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, context

I am using the following code to create citations from a BibTeX file:

```
\usebtxdataset[default][/home/username/external.bib]
\setupbtx[dataset=default]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]

\starttext
    \input knuth
    \cite[lucas2004]
    \placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

Since ConTeXt currently has no support for Turabian/Chicago, I created my own custom macros that builds a bibliography page fitting that style. As such, I no longer need the `\placelistofpublications` line in my code, as I don't want the APA-style bibliography to appear.

If I remove `\placelistofpublications`, strangely all citations disappear from the document, I just get empty "()"'s.

How can I use citations in my document, without calling `\placelistofpublications`?

Comment: The [publications manual](https://pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mkiv-publications.pdf) says on p. 37: "Both the citation and the list must be rendered. For example, a common error would be to omit (or comment-out) the list rendering during the writing stage of a document."

Comment: Maybe you can do `\setbox\scratchbox=\vbox{\placelistofpublications}` to fool it.

Comment: That works great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these situations you can use a dirty trick to fool ConTeXt into thinking that something has been typeset. Instead of typesetting the bibliography normally, you typeset it in a box and store the result without ever actually using the box.  This is facilitated by the `\start...\stopnointerference` environment.

```
\usebtxdataset[default][publ-imp-test.bib]
\setupbtx[dataset=default]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]

\starttext
    \input knuth
    \cite[test-article]
    \startnointerference
        \placelistofpublications
    \stopnointerference
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: You can replace the `\setbox` line with the `nointerference` environment which does the same but looks better, e.g. `\startnointerference \placelistofpublications \stopnointerference`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster Thanks, very helpful!